# Multiple file upload pending

Tags: .net, angular, iis, postman

status shows pending and no response when trying to upload more than one file to the IIS server using angular and Dotnet core backend. this works on the local developing machine but the only problem after published. I have checked API with POSTMAN and the same result.

Comment: Please provide more information. Any errors? Just stuck forever? No time outs? Does the API even receive it and then go into deadlock?

Comment: @misha130: no errors and not even hitting to the controller, also can't debug because it is working perfectly on development. the problem is after i published